# How to add multi line comments in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

How to add multi line comments in knockout js in magento
Such as we have add single line and multi lines comments on other languages.

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [how to ask question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `/* This doesn't work?*/`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a multi-line comment in Knockout JS, you are supposed to comment the code line by line.

You can use the following syntax:

```
<!-- kocomment foreach: { data: $record().elems(), as: 'elem'}  -->
//Other code
<!-- /kocomment -->
```

This effectively turns ko statements into a simple html comment (knockout does not care for such comments).

Just make sure to comment out both opening and closing statement

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the answer in case it solved your problem.